# Ошибка при написании сайта на django

Tags: python, django

При написании на Python django в режиме админа при вводе в поле и подтверждении выскакивает ошибка "IntegrityError at /admin/polls/choice/add/ NOT NULL constraint failed: polls_choice.votes". Могу предоставить любой код. Я пишу на django впервые, а в интернете решения не нашел. Код добавляет опрос на сайт.

Comment: Приведите проблемный участок кода. Админку, модели, описание того, что делаете.

Answer (score 0):

Это с базой данных проблема. Скорее всего вы пытаетесь записать null, в питоне это None, в ячейку votes.